# How can I automatically populate the runfile option with corresponding json files based on selected runtype using PySimpleGUI in Python?

Tags: python, auto-populate

By using the PySimpleGUI package how can I automatically populate a runfile option with the corresponding json file that I have. So that when I select the runtype in the combo option it automatically imports the corresponding json file to the runfile?